# Breaking 1 String into 2 Strings based on special characters using python

Tags: python, string, character, substring

I am working with python and I am new to it. I am looking for a way to take a string and split it into two smaller strings. An example of the string is below

```
wholeString = '102..109'
```

And what I am trying to get is:

```
a = '102'
b = '109'
```

The information will always be separated by two periods like shown above, but the number of characters before and after can range anywhere from 1 - 10 characters in length. I am writing a loop that counts characters before and after the periods and then makes a slice based on those counts, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way that someone knew about.
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
a, b = wholeString.split('..')
```

It'll put each value into the corresponding variables.

Comment: Thank You, this is such a better solution than iterating over each character.

Comment: No prob! That way of assigning variables is one of those cool Python tricks that comes in handy every once in a while.

Comment: @RocketDonkey: elegant solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`string.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
split_up = [s.strip() for s in wholeString.split("..")]
```

This code will also strip off leading and trailing whitespace so you are just left with the values you are looking for. split_up will be a list of these values.